# print syntax in v2.7 not compatible in v3.4?

Tags: python

Is the print syntax in v2.7 not compatible in v3.4?

i remember being told not that

```
print 0.3
```

won't work.

And i learned

```
print '%f' % 1/3
```

Now in v3.4 here's what happened:

```
print(1/3)
```

output: `0.3333333333333333`

```
print `'%f' % 1/3`
```

output: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
print('%3.3f" % 1/3)
```

output: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

```
print('%(number)3.3f' % {'number':1/3})
```

output: 0.333

Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print('%3.3f" % 1/3)`

You start with a single quote and finish with a double quote

`print('%3.3f' % 1/3)` or `print("%3.3f" % 1/3)` will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes the syntax changed. Look at https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html for closer information. Although the formatted print statements still work. You just have a typo there. (biggest difference are the parentheses, 3.x requires them 2.7 does not)